# Parsing string token with bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, text-processing

I have this output (from a previous command):

```
aaa         something
bbb         someother
ccc         blabla
```

For each line, I would like to create a file whose name is the first token, and whose content is the second token (for example for the first line I would like a file named 'aaa' that contains the text 'something')

How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple awk script solution. The second field is written to a file named from the first field.

```
awk '{ print $2 > $1 }' your-file
```

Comment: It doesn't work..

Comment: @RubanSavvy, that certainly works for me: http://pastebin.com/XRhcSLPa

Comment: `awk: (FILENAME=ru.txt FNR=1) fatal: expression for '>' redirection has null string value` I had this error.

Comment: I tried the same file content but with diff file name..

Comment: I'm using CentOS 6 gwak.

Comment: @RubanSavvy check your file again, you have probably added an extra blank line somewhere. If `$1` is undefined anywhere (as it will be if there is a blank line), the command will work fine but give that error. So, you probably have an extra line and did not check the contents of the generated files to see if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

@suspectus's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105863/22222) is right on. For more complicated cases where you might have something like this:

```
aaa         something, something more and a bit extra
bbb         someother someother more and a few more chars
ccc         blabla blah blah boloum bloum bleh
```

And would like the name to be the first field and the contents to be the rest of the line, try this:

```
awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){ printf $i" " >> $1 };print "" >> $1;}' file
```

Or, in Perl:

```
perl -ane 'open($f,">",shift(@F));print $f "@F\n"' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
your_command | while read name text; do
        echo "$test" > $name
    done
```

Note that the `IFS` envoronment variable is going to influence the way this is parsed (word splitting) and that you have to be extra careful about **not** having "special" characters in the file names (and the text).